# Call static method on classes without namspaces

Tags: php, symfony, class, symfony-3.2

I have a library that don't uses namespaces but uses only static methods, how could I make it available throughout the application? I'm using Symfony 3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in your `composer.json` file for autoloading:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["/path/to/my/file/with/functions.php"]
}
```

Read more: https://codingexplained.com/coding/php/composer-autoloading-third-party-libraries-without-namespaces

Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload` to rebuild the cached autoloader.